# ¿Cómo enviar/recibir peticiones JSON y XML por HTTPs en Java?

Tags: java, json, xml, https

Buenas tardes a todos,

Os explico un poco el proyecto. Yo tengo un Dynamic Web Project en Eclipse y un compañero que está en Lituania me enviará una petición en JSON. Yo quiero recibir esta petición en JSON en mi proyecto. Posteriormente esta petición yo quiero tansformarla en XML (esto es fácil) y después esta petición XML quiero volver a enviarla a este compañero mio. Todo esto debo hacerlo con HTTPs. 
¿Esto es posible?

Espero sus respuestas.
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y tiempo.

Un saludo a todos,

Answer (score -1):

Te sugiero usar SpringBoot con servicio RESTfull, aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como resolverlo.

[RESTfull](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-rest-service-with-spring-boot)

[HTTPS SpringBoot](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-example/)

Comment: Hola AndyC, 
Lo primero gracias por tu comentario. 
Lo segundo, ¿cómo puedo recibir la petición HTTPs?
Recuerda que no es HTTP sino HTTPs. ¿Y después para volver a enviarla?
Basta que me copies las instrucciones de java.
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
Un saludo,

Comment: Revisa esto. Mi sugerencia es que revises SpringBoot que es muy potente para servicios web. La otra manera pudiera ser JEE. De cualquier manera te envio un link

Answer (score -1):

aqui puedes encontrar información que te ayude a adaptar una solucion a tu problema.

http://cxf.apache.org

https://jersey.github.io

http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Comment: Una respuesta que sea sólo un enlace no es una buena respuesta (ej. si Apache archiva CXF y lo mueve, tu enlace ya no sirve). Si la pregunta es muy amplia para entrar en detalles, pon un comentario y pide más detalles al OP.